# How to integrate Gmail oauth2 in android app?

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I have tried to run below source code for gmail integration.
http://ddewaele.github.io/AndroidOauth2GoogleApiJavaClient/

I have followed all step which are mentioned but i am getting below error.

**Error**

*"Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:
     3.6.0:generate-sources (execution: default-generate-sources, phase: generate-sources)
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:
     3.6.0:proguard (execution: default-proguard, phase: process-classes)"*

Would you please guide me to resolve this issue? Or how to integrate gmail integration into app?

Comment: I think it has something to do with configuring m2e - http://wiki.eclipse.org/M2E_plugin_execution_not_covered but I'm stuck where you are too

Comment: you have to include all jar file if you don't want to use maven. I did same and working fine in my application.